# How to renumber residues (start from 1 in continuation among chains) in pdb file in python?

Tags: python, biopython

I want to do continuous renumbering a pdb file having multiple chains(A,H,L). Some of the chains have insertion codes attached to the residue position (e.g., 190A etc.). Can anybody help me how to write this code?
[Example of pdb file with insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG9Yj.jpg)
[image: expected output]

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279008/how-to-replace-pdb-atom-entries-with-an-altered-pdb-file-that-just-contains-atom/70311342#70311342 ---> first answer look into the code for the # renumber atoms in new structure block of code

Comment: so that 29,29A ---> 1,1A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my attempt using Biopython:

input file : `testA.pdb` :

```
ATOM     25  N   ALA E   5      48.087  97.950  74.514  1.00  9.33           N  
ATOM     26  CA  ALA E   5      48.052  99.292  73.904  1.00  9.37           C  
ATOM     27  C   ALA E   5      47.483 100.285  74.935  1.00  9.65           C  
ATOM     28  O   ALA E   5      47.693 101.493  74.908  1.00  9.11           O  
ATOM     29  CB  ALA E   5      47.247  99.339  72.623  1.00  8.31           C  
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   6      46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   6      46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   6      46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   6      46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   6      44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   6      44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   6      43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   6      42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   6A     46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   6A     46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   6A     46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   6A     46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   6A     44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   6A     44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   6A     43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   6A     42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C  
ATOM     38  N   GLN E   7      47.184 100.177  79.159  1.00 10.08           N  
ATOM     39  CA  GLN E   7      47.750  99.648  80.383  1.00 10.85           C  
ATOM     40  C   GLN E   7      46.749  99.311  81.476  1.00 10.94           C  
ATOM     41  O   GLN E   7      45.812 100.068  81.762  1.00 10.33           O  
ATOM     42  CB  GLN E   7      48.855 100.550  80.962  1.00 11.19           C  
ATOM     43  CG  GLN E   7      50.227 100.292  80.353  1.00 11.71           C  
ATOM     44  CD  GLN E   7      50.656 101.322  79.346  1.00 12.04           C  
ATOM     45  OE1 GLN E   7      50.015 101.625  78.348  1.00 11.94           O  
ATOM     46  NE2 GLN E   7      51.811 101.943  79.591  1.00 12.40           N  
ATOM     47  N   PRO E   8      46.990  98.145  82.066  1.00 11.13           N  
ATOM     48  CA  PRO E   8      46.204  97.689  83.212  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     49  C   PRO E   8      46.688  98.594  84.352  1.00 11.77           C  
ATOM     50  O   PRO E   8      47.885  98.899  84.409  1.00 11.72           O  
ATOM     51  CB  PRO E   8      46.586  96.236  83.432  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     52  CG  PRO E   8      47.935  96.031  82.787  1.00 11.65           C  
ATOM     53  CD  PRO E   8      48.114  97.207  81.829  1.00 11.20           C
```

my code :

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBIO, PDBParser

from Bio.PDB.Chain import Chain
from Bio.PDB.Residue import Residue


# to work with some non orthodox pdbs
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


io = PDBIO()
parser = PDBParser()


# my_pdb_structure = parser.get_structure('test', 'test.pdb')
my_pdb_structure = parser.get_structure('test', 'testA.pdb')

print(my_pdb_structure)


# renumber residue in my_pdb_structure
residue_N = 1
for model in my_pdb_structure:
    for chain in model:
            for residue in chain:
                print(residue.id)
                if 'A' in residue.id[2]:
                    residue.id = (residue.id[0], residue_N-1, residue.id[2])
                    print('----',residue.id)
                    
                else:
                    residue.id = (residue.id[0], residue_N, residue.id[2])
                    print('----',residue.id)
                    residue_N += 1


# this bit just print the renumbered my_pdb_structure                    
print('\n stucture with renumbered atoms : \n___________________________________')                  
for model in my_pdb_structure:
    for chain in model:
            for residue in chain:
                print(residue, residue.id)

        
io.set_structure(my_pdb_structure)
# io.save('renumbered.pdb') 
io.save('renumberedA.pdb',  preserve_atom_numbering=True)
```

output   `renumberedA.pdb`:

```
ATOM     25  N   ALA E   1      48.087  97.950  74.514  1.00  9.33           N  
ATOM     26  CA  ALA E   1      48.052  99.292  73.904  1.00  9.37           C  
ATOM     27  C   ALA E   1      47.483 100.285  74.935  1.00  9.65           C  
ATOM     28  O   ALA E   1      47.693 101.493  74.908  1.00  9.11           O  
ATOM     29  CB  ALA E   1      47.247  99.339  72.623  1.00  8.31           C  
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   2      46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   2      46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   2      46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   2      46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   2      44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   2      44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   2      43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   2      42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C  
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   2A     46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   2A     46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   2A     46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   2A     46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   2A     44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   2A     44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   2A     43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   2A     42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C  
ATOM     38  N   GLN E   3      47.184 100.177  79.159  1.00 10.08           N  
ATOM     39  CA  GLN E   3      47.750  99.648  80.383  1.00 10.85           C  
ATOM     40  C   GLN E   3      46.749  99.311  81.476  1.00 10.94           C  
ATOM     41  O   GLN E   3      45.812 100.068  81.762  1.00 10.33           O  
ATOM     42  CB  GLN E   3      48.855 100.550  80.962  1.00 11.19           C  
ATOM     43  CG  GLN E   3      50.227 100.292  80.353  1.00 11.71           C  
ATOM     44  CD  GLN E   3      50.656 101.322  79.346  1.00 12.04           C  
ATOM     45  OE1 GLN E   3      50.015 101.625  78.348  1.00 11.94           O  
ATOM     46  NE2 GLN E   3      51.811 101.943  79.591  1.00 12.40           N  
ATOM     47  N   PRO E   4      46.990  98.145  82.066  1.00 11.13           N  
ATOM     48  CA  PRO E   4      46.204  97.689  83.212  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     49  C   PRO E   4      46.688  98.594  84.352  1.00 11.77           C  
ATOM     50  O   PRO E   4      47.885  98.899  84.409  1.00 11.72           O  
ATOM     51  CB  PRO E   4      46.586  96.236  83.432  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     52  CG  PRO E   4      47.935  96.031  82.787  1.00 11.65           C  
ATOM     53  CD  PRO E   4      48.114  97.207  81.829  1.00 11.20           C  
TER      53      PRO E   4                                                       
END
```

the code just load the pdb file throught PDBParser() and loop over the pdb structure object changing id of residues starting from 1 and adding +1 on each loop, then saves the renubered_structure through PDBIO() (first set the structure then saves it).

I dont know the inners of Biopython for PDB parsing and PDB structure objects, my code works only on your test input, that is the residue having an A is always after the one same residue without the A, you can run tests with different input pdbs to check it out

As per your comment and my input above you can get this output:

```
ATOM     25  N   ALA E   1      48.087  97.950  74.514  1.00  9.33           N  
ATOM     26  CA  ALA E   1      48.052  99.292  73.904  1.00  9.37           C  
ATOM     27  C   ALA E   1      47.483 100.285  74.935  1.00  9.65           C  
ATOM     28  O   ALA E   1      47.693 101.493  74.908  1.00  9.11           O  
ATOM     29  CB  ALA E   1      47.247  99.339  72.623  1.00  8.31           C  
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   2      46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   2      46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   2      46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   2      46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   2      44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   2      44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   2      43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   2      42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C  
ATOM     30  N   ILE E   3      46.802  99.657  75.862  1.00  9.99           N  
ATOM     31  CA  ILE E   3      46.118 100.279  77.004  1.00 10.34           C  
ATOM     32  C   ILE E   3      46.521  99.491  78.253  1.00 10.35           C  
ATOM     33  O   ILE E   3      46.292  98.274  78.348  1.00  9.61           O  
ATOM     34  CB  ILE E   3      44.613 100.230  76.772  1.00 11.05           C  
ATOM     35  CG1 ILE E   3      44.269 100.841  75.413  1.00 11.39           C  
ATOM     36  CG2 ILE E   3      43.845 100.913  77.879  1.00 11.06           C  
ATOM     37  CD1 ILE E   3      42.926 100.408  74.814  1.00 11.29           C  
ATOM     38  N   GLN E   4      47.184 100.177  79.159  1.00 10.08           N  
ATOM     39  CA  GLN E   4      47.750  99.648  80.383  1.00 10.85           C  
ATOM     40  C   GLN E   4      46.749  99.311  81.476  1.00 10.94           C  
ATOM     41  O   GLN E   4      45.812 100.068  81.762  1.00 10.33           O  
ATOM     42  CB  GLN E   4      48.855 100.550  80.962  1.00 11.19           C  
ATOM     43  CG  GLN E   4      50.227 100.292  80.353  1.00 11.71           C  
ATOM     44  CD  GLN E   4      50.656 101.322  79.346  1.00 12.04           C  
ATOM     45  OE1 GLN E   4      50.015 101.625  78.348  1.00 11.94           O  
ATOM     46  NE2 GLN E   4      51.811 101.943  79.591  1.00 12.40           N  
ATOM     47  N   PRO E   5      46.990  98.145  82.066  1.00 11.13           N  
ATOM     48  CA  PRO E   5      46.204  97.689  83.212  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     49  C   PRO E   5      46.688  98.594  84.352  1.00 11.77           C  
ATOM     50  O   PRO E   5      47.885  98.899  84.409  1.00 11.72           O  
ATOM     51  CB  PRO E   5      46.586  96.236  83.432  1.00 11.66           C  
ATOM     52  CG  PRO E   5      47.935  96.031  82.787  1.00 11.65           C  
ATOM     53  CD  PRO E   5      48.114  97.207  81.829  1.00 11.20           C  
TER      53      PRO E   5                                                       
END
```

just changing the renumbering block of code, with the next one:

```
# renumber residue in my_pdb_structure
residue_N = 1
for model in my_pdb_structure:
    for chain in model:
            for residue in chain:
                print(residue.id)
                residue.id = (residue.id[0], residue_N, " ")
                print('----',residue.id)
                residue_N += 1
```

this will renumber all residues starting counting from 1 and deletig all the As or other letter in the pdb

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The renumber I want to o is in continuation. Which means the 6A in your example should become 3 instead of 2A. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Radz  I updated my answer, dont forget to accept it if it suits your needs and helped you solve your problem, I am sure there are a lot of other ways (i.e. using other parsers or building your ones)